# Im trying to solve this SQL error I cannot solve

Tags: sql

Trying to put this together but I keep getting Ambiguous errors, the train_id is in both the trainer table as the PK and in the workout table as a FK.

```
SELECT train_id AS "Trainer ID", count(workout_id) AS "Number of workouts"
FROM trainer JOIN workout
ON trainer.train_id = workout.train_id;
```

I was expecting it to give me all the trainers Id's in one column and the count of all their workouts, I did COUNT(workout_id) because the workout_id is tied to a workout for individuals so counting this gives me the count I need.

Comment: It's good programming practice to _qualify_ all column, at least when several tables are involved. Just like you do in the ON clause.

Comment: BTW. no need to JOIN the tables, you already have the train_id in the workout table.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing a `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT t.train_id AS "Trainer ID",
       COUNT(w.workout_id) AS "Number of workouts"
FROM trainer t
INNER JOIN workout w ON t.train_id = w.train_id
GROUP BY t.train_id;
```